# Find missing dates of each product where multiple products are stored in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

I have a table structure similar to this which tracks some product data in a daily base:

```
product_id|columnA|columnB|my_date|
   1      |  a1   |  a2   |2021-03-03|
   1      |  a1   |  a2   |2021-03-04|
   1      |  a1   |  a2   |2021-03-06|
   1      |  a1   |  a2   |2021-03-07|
   1      |  a1   |  a2   |2021-03-10|
   2      |  a1   |  a2   |2021-06-01|
   2      |  a1   |  a2   |2021-06-03|
  ...
 (more product_id)
```

As you can see, `|2021-03-05|`, `|2021-03-08|` and `|2021-03-09|` are missing for `product_id` 1 and `|2021-06-02|`  is missing for `product_id`
2 .

I want to get all the missing dates for each `product_id`, the result table should look like:

```
product_id|mssing_date|
   1      |2021-03-05|
   1      |2021-03-08|
   1      |2021-03-09|
   2      |2021-06-02|
  ...          ....
other_ids |other_missing dates|
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to general all combinations of products and dates.  Then remove them . . . one method is a left join:

```
select p.product_id, d.my_date
from (select distinct product_id from t) p cross join
     (select distinct my_date from t) d left join
     t
     on t.product_id = p.product_id and t.my_date = p.my_date
where t.product_id is null;
```

EDIT:

For the revised question (based on the comments), you can just calculate the date range and use that for the query:

```
select p.product_id, d.my_date
from (select product_id, min(my_date) as min_my_date, max(my_date) as max_my_date
      from t
      group by product_id
     ) p join
     (select distinct my_date from t) d
     on d.my_date bewteen p.min_my_date and p.max_my_date left join
     t
     on t.product_id = p.product_id and
        t.my_date = p.my_date
where t.product_id is null;
```

These methods assume that there is at least one row for each date in the data.  In not, you need a different way to generate the dates, such as a calendar table or recursive CTE.

Comment: For synthetic non-indexed rowset NOT EXISTS may be faster than LEFT JOIN. But may not, of course.. must be tested.

Comment: Tested. 1000 products, ~400 dates per product (~1000 dates total), index by (product, date). Warm caches. LEFT JOIN ~ 7.5sec, NOT EXISTS ~ 2.1 sec.

Comment: @Rick . . . `t` is your table name.  `p` and `d` are table aliases, which MySQL requires for derived tables (and they are recommended even if not required).

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I've re-edited the sample data. The dates of each product are not the same.

Comment: @Rick . . . That doesn't make sense.  If the dates aren't the same, how do you know which are missing?

Comment: I only need to get the missing dates between the dates (`min(my_date)` of each product id and max(my_date) of each prodcut id) of each product.

Comment: I still don't understand how you can get the missing date with that sql. e.g. `|2021-03-05|` is missing for `product_id` 1, `|2021-03-05|` is not the original table. How does your sql produce `|2021-03-05|` from joins?

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH RECURSIVE all_dates AS (
   SELECT '2021-01-01' AS d_date
 UNION
   SELECT d_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   FROM all_dates
   WHERE d_date < '2021-12-31')
SELECT product_id, d_date
FROM all_dates
LEFT JOIN products ON d_date = product.date
WHERE product.date IS NULL;
```

Using MySQL 8

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224182/generate-dates-between-date-ranges-in-mysql